# regular expressions to replace money pattern

Tags: php, regex

I would like to ask for help with this, I wanted to check for a string
matching a decimal followed by a letter (15M, 15.3M, 15T or 15.3T) and
replace it with zeroes.

Like these:
15M -> 15000000
15.3M -> 15300000
15T -> 15000
15.3T -> 15300

I tried doing this with `str_replace` but can't get it right. Hope
someone can help me.

Comment: Ooops, I did not see these comments before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"T" could be "thousand" or "trillion", you know.

```
$s = "15.7T";

$factors = Array('T' => 1000, 'M' => 1000000, 'B' => 1000000000.);

$matches = Array();
if (0 < preg_match('/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)([TMB])/', $s, $matches)) {
    print("$s -> " . $matches[1] * $factors[$matches[2]]);
}
```

prints:

```
15.7T -> 15700
```

edit:

Anchoring (makes any garbage on the front or back mean no match):

```
'/^(...)$/'
```

You may want to make whitespace allowed, however:

```
'/^\s*(...)\s*$/'
```

You can also use "\d" in place of "[0-9]:

```
'/(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)([TMB])/'
```

Case insensitivity:

```
'/.../i'
...
print("$s -> " . $matches[1] * $factors[strtoupper($matches[2])]);
```

Optional factor:

```
'/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)([TMB])?/'
$value = $matches[1];
$factor = isset($matches[2]) ? $factors[$matches[2]] : 1;
$output = $value * $factor;
```

Use printf to control output formatting:

```
print($value) -> 1.57E+10
printf("%f", $value);  -> 15700000000.000000
printf("%.0f", $value);  -> 15700000000
```

[Stephan202 recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134973/regular-expressions-to-replace-money-pattern/1135023#1135023) a clever trick, put the "?" (optional) within the parens and you're guaranteed a match string, it just might be blank.  Then you can use the blank as an array key to get the default value without having to test whether it matched or not.

Putting all that together:

```
$factors = Array('' => 1, 'T' => 1e3, 'M' => 1e6, 'B' => 1e9);
if (0 < preg_match('/^\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)([TMB]?)\s*$/i', $s, $matches)) {
    $value = $matches[1];
    $factor = $factors[$matches[2]];
    printf("'%s' -> %.0f", $s, $value * $factor);
}
```

Comment: +1. However, you might want to anchor the pattern as well as making the factor optional just in case there are numbers without data.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to keep it simple, since there were no clues about what context the input might be in.

Comment: hey i just checked, if its in millions, it returns the number in exponential form(1.4M -> 1.4E+6), how will i convert that with zeroes?

Comment: Hmm, I can get "15.7B  -> 15700000000", but I have "precision =  14" set in my PHP.ini file.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Stephan202, which part of the code will the ? be? The default value is appealing

Comment: I was referring to 1. the change from "([TMB])?" to "([TMB]?)" 2. the change from "isset($matches[2]) ? $factors[$matches[2]] : 1;" to simply "$factors[$matches[2]]" and 3. the addition of '' => 1 to the factor array.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative version which performs a conversion on all prices found:

```
  $multiply = array('' => 1, 'T' => 1000, 'M' => 1000000);

  function convert($matches) {
    global $multiply;
    return $matches[1] * $multiply[$matches[3]];
  }

  $text = '15M 15.3M 15.3T 15';
  print(preg_replace_callback('/(\d+(\.\d+)?)(\w?)/', 'convert', $text));
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't even know that function existed.  It would be even cooler if you could make the factor mapping a parameter and pass in a curried version for the callback, but currying in PHP is a pain IIRC.  Clever use of the blank string as a key, too.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %factors = (
    B => 1_000_000_000,
    M => 1_000_000,
    T => 1_000,
);

while ( <DATA> ) {
    next unless m{
        ^
        (?<number> -? [0-9]+ (?:\.[0-9]+)? )
        (?<factor>B|M|T)?
        $
    }x;
    my $number = $+{factor}
               ? sprintf( '%.0f', $+{number} * $factors{ $+{factor} } )
               : $+{number}
               ;
    print $number, "\n";
}

__DATA__
15M
15B
15T
15.3M
15.3B
15.3T
15
15.3
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> z
15000000
15000000000
15000
15300000
15300000000
15300
15
15.3
```

Comment: can you translate it in php? i don't know perl, thanks for answering

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize this was a PHP question. Codebender's solution is somewhat equivalent to mine.

Comment: Too bad PHP doesn't support named captures, that's pretty cool.

Comment: They are a recent addition to Perl, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea how to make it in one regular expression, here is my try in Ruby.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def trans s
h={"M"=>10**6 ,"T"=>10**3}
a = s.split(/[MT]/) + [s.split("").last]
(a[0].to_f * h[a[1]]).to_i
end


puts trans "15M"
puts trans "15.3M"
puts trans "15T"
puts trans "15.3T"
```